# Flutter access session as Json array

Tags: json, flutter, session

i have added a json array in session. when i try to access the array, it shows as string. that is without any double quotes. but i want it as json array. Am i missing anything here ? please help.
this is the array :

```dart
var login_data = {"success":1, "user":{"id":"13","firstname":"Reda","lastname":"Estyu"},"shop_name" :"Market"}
await FlutterSession().set('session_data', login_data);
var get_data = await FlutterSession().get("session_data");
print(get_data);
```

after accessing it from session it looks like this :
`{success:1, user:{id:13,firstname:Reda,lastname:Estyu},shop_name :Market}`

Comment: result of `jsonDecode(get_data)` may help you. See [JSON and serialization](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json)

Comment: i tried it already. but got this error : _TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String')

Comment: Please specify the dependency you are using here.

Comment: flutter_session 0.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `Map` returns `Map` and setting `String` returns `String` - makes sense. Encode `Map` to `String` before setting.

```
await FlutterSession().set('session_data', jsonEncode(login_data));
...
var get_data = jsonDecode(await FlutterSession().get("session_data"));
```

Comment: It worked !! I thought there is no need to encode before setting into the session since it is a json array... but after encoding and decoding the session it worked. thank you so much